# Horizontal scrolling div with images won't display inline

Tags: css, image, scroll

I'm trying to create a div with a fixed size that contains images only. I'd like them to be the height of the div, display inline, and scroll through them horizontally. I'm having trouble making this work. I'd to do this as simply as possible. What am I missing?

Comment: What does your code look like?

Comment: Oh, right. Sorry, a problem would help. The images won't display inline. The image that's as wide as the div get's pushed down to the next line.

Comment: Code looks like this:

'.frame { width: 800px; height: 530px; overflow: auto; }
.frame img { height: 530px; float: left; }'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need `white-space: nowrap` on the element with `overflow` in order to tell it that it shouldn't treat separate images as word-wrappable.

Answer (score 0):

Set overflow:scroll, width and height on the div, set the images to display:inline height:100% (or maybe float:left).